# nginx warns server name has strange symbols

Tags: nginx

I have a domain that includes a dash, e.g. `the-domain.com`, when I made a server block with a server name of my domain and restarted nginx, I got a warning:

> Restarting nginx: nginx: [warn] server name "/var/www/domain.com/www/thedomain" has strange symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com:56
>   nginx.

So I changed the domain to another one I have, it still continues to say the same error from above. I don't understand why it's saying this when I change it to an appropiate one?

This the repeated error:

> Restarting nginx: nginx: [warn] server name "/var/www/domain.com/www/domaindir" has strange symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain.com:56
>   nginx.

My configuration file for the domain is shown below:

```
server {

    server_name     domain.com;

    root            /var/www/domain.com/www;
    index           index.php index.htm index.html;
    error_page      404 /404.html;
    error_page      500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    access_log      /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/domain.com/logs/errors.log;

    error_page 404  /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {

    server_name     ~^(.+)\.domain\.com$;

    set             $file_path $1;

    root            /var/www/domain.com/www/$file_path;
    index           index.php index.htm index.html;
    error_page      404 /404.html;
    error_page      500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    access_log      /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/domain.com/logs/errors.log;

    location /
    {
        try_files $uri /$uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {

    server_name     anotherdomain.org

    root            /var/www/domain.com/www/domaindir;  # this is line 56
    index           index.php index.htm index.html;
    error_page      404 /404.html;
    error_page      500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    access_log      /var/www/domain.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log       /var/www/domain.com/logs/errors.log;


    location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What seems to be the problem making this error thrown?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Easy: missing ";" after `server_name` at line 54.

Answer (score 1):

For me the cause of this error was having 'http://' in the server_name.

i.e. I changed this:

```
server {
    listen <Server name>:80;
    server_name <DNS name> http://localhost:28080;
    ...
```

To this:

```
server {
    listen <Server name>:80;
    server_name <DNS name> localhost:28080;
    ...
```